# How to get end of month from format yyyyMM to yyyyMMdd

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in format as
`yyyyMM`
in a table and a column of date as `yyyyMMdd` in another table,
which is month end value.

I want to compare both in a query where I can't perform any action on 2nd one.

is there any way to convert `yyyyMM` to end of month as `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: The best thing you could do is rebuild these columns as a `DateTime` fields instead of `varchar`, where you supply the first day of the month for the field with no day value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a total hack, but you can do this:

```
DECLARE @BadDate CHAR(6) = '202004';
SELECT EOMONTH(@BadDate + '01');
```

Answer is:

```
2020-04-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(6) = '202004';
select format(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@d+'01')+1,0)), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da15d1c57a64fa99fb2ae9cdcc9f638d).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it -

Mine char date is formatted as MONTH = "yyyy-mm"

I first did string manipulation to get the first day of the month.   Then applied the EOMMONTH function to the first day of the month to get the last day of the month.

SELECT *
,FirstDayOfMonth = RIGHT(MONTH,2) + '-01-' + LEFT(MONTH,4)
,LastDayOfMonth  = EOMONTH(RIGHT(MONTH,2) + '-01-' + LEFT(MONTH,4))
FROM MonthTable